# Movie Clip through Display Object Not working correctly

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flashdevelop, flash-cs6, displayobject

Hey everyone so I have a movie Clip called `popEffect` that i want to show on the current `bubbles` that are being clicked by the mouse. Now Whenever I click on a Bubble everything works correctly they get removed from the stage, but the problem I am having is that the `popEffect` is not positioned to the current `bubbles` that are being clicked. Instead they are positioned at a different bubble that shows on the screen in the display object array.

Here is how I have it all set up:

```
private function addBubbles(e:TimerEvent):void 
    {

        bubbles = new mcBubbles();
        stage.addChild(bubbles);
        aBubbleArray.push(bubbles);
        bubbles.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bubblesBeingClicked);
    }
```

Then the BubblesBeingClicked function:

```
private function bubblesBeingClicked(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
         var BubblePop:DisplayObject = e.target as DisplayObject; // HERE is your clicked square
         var i:int = aBubbleArray.indexOf(BubblePop); // and HERE is your index in the array

         if (i < 0) 
         {

            // the MC is out of the array
               //trace("Pop Clicked");
               onBubbleIsClicked(BubblePop);
               aBubbleArray.splice(i, 1);
               BubblePop.parent.removeChild(BubblePop);
               //Remove Listeners!!!
               BubblePop.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onBubbleIsClicked);
               // Null
               BubblePop = null;



         }

    }
```

Finally my onBubbleIsClicked function where i have the `popEffect` located:

```
private function onBubbleIsClicked(bubblePop:DisplayObject):void 
    {
        nScore++;
        updateHighScore();



         //Pop Effect
         popEffect = new mcBubblePop();
         stage.addChild(popEffect);
         popEffect.x = bubbles.x;
         popEffect.y = bubbles.y;
       }
```

Can anyone see why the `popEffect` wont position on the current bubble that is being popped? Its acting really weird.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is this:

```
popEffect.x = bubbles.x;
popEffect.y = bubbles.y;
```

As far as I can understand, `bubbles` is a member variable in the class (you are using it in the `addBubbles` function. Inside `onBubbleIsClicked`, you provide `bubblePop`, but do not use it. You are using `bubbles` instead, which is actually the last instance you've created inside the tick function!

So every time you create `popEffect`, you actually assign the `x` and `y` to the **latest** created `bubblePop`.

**Some advises**:

- Do not use member variables that often. They are used **WHEN** you need to use a variable between functions. In your case, `bubbles` is a variable that is used **only** inside the creational function. You even put them into an array! And because you override it with a new one every time you create an instance, your member variables just saves the last one. Is this really needed? Same with `popEffect`, does anyone else uses it, as it's again just the last one? Such things create mistakes, as you see..
- I truly don't understand what this means: `if (i < 0)`. You search if the object you've clicked is not in the array? Well if it is not (how come?!), then what's the meaning of `aBubbleArray.splice(i, 1);`? Since `i < 0`, you actually splice with negative value, so you splice some **other** element! Plan what you want to do, thing logically and then do the actual code. If the object is not in the array, then why do you remove anything from the array?
- Start formatting your code better. Read about camel case and variables scope.
- Try to manage your logic better. For example this is pretty awkward: `BubblePop.parent.removeChild(BubblePop);`, as long as you've added it by using `stage.addChild(bubbles);`. So isn't it more simple to use `stage.removeChild(child);`? There are some rules in programming (especially in Flash), like 'what added it should remove it'. This will keep you safe in future.

Good luck!